# SUMPRODUCT formula not working

Tags: excel

I have the following formula in a cell which I’m trying to locate a set of numbers in a range but it’s not working and I don’t know why.

My range of cells is A20:A40 TO Z20:Z40. The Find(“-”, refers to cell A3 which has a 1- (the 1- refers to a set of numbers, anything that starts with a 1-, could be 1-10 or 1-99, 99 is the limit).

I’m not sure what the B19 reference is (nothing in that cell) or the 5 or the <2 in the formula.

```
=SUMPRODUCT((LEFT($A$20:$Z$40,FIND("-",$A$20:$Z$40&"-"))=A3)*(MOD(COLUMN($A$20:$Z$40)-COLUMN(B19),5)<2))
```

Really appreciate any help.

Comment: `(MOD(COLUMN($A$20:$Z$40)-COLUMN(B19),5)<2)` is a spacer to skip certain columns in the count.  do you want all the columns?  If so replace that whole part with `1`

Comment: Thanks so much Scott that was the answer I needed. Have a great day.  Mike